# Enforce site-wide SSL on Debian LAMP

Tags: ssl

I have a Debian/Linux Lenny LAMP server with Plesk Panel 10.2. I have a PHP/MySQL webapp deployed in a Plesk "webspace".

I want to enforce SSL site-wide.

Do I just forward port 80 to 443?  For my single domain cert, do I forward `www.example.com` to `example.com` or do I forward `example.com` to `www.example.com`?

Should this happen with `.htaccess` or some `VirtualHost` config file?

Answer (score 2):

I would use mod_rewrite.

Enable mod_rewrite and add something like this to your vhost config

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !On
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in your VirtualHost config. For example have a VirtualHost for the HTTP protocol on port 80 that redirects your users to the HTTPS version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin you@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```